# distributing k pennies to n children

Tags: probability-distributions

there are 100 pennies and 10 children

every child can get either 5, 10 or 20 pennies

How many ways to do in this case?

---

I assumed that n = pennies, and k = children

so if first child can get 5, 10 or 20 pennies which is n-5, n-10, or n-20

if I keep going like that, It feels like i am counting all possibilities.

I just don't know how to approach and solve this question.

Comment: Hello @ANDY, welcome to MSE. When you type mathematics in your question, please use MathJax. In this [link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you will find a small tutorial how to use MathJax.

Comment: It rather depends on what methods you want to use.  For example you could take the coefficient of $x^{100}$ in the expansion of $\left(x^5+x^{10}+x^{20}\right)^{10}$.  Or you could spot you need twice as many children getting $5$ pennies as get $20$ pennies: for example there are $\frac{10!}{6!1!3!}=840$ ways $6$ children get $5$ and $1$ child gets $10$ and $3$ children get $20$.  Or you could use a spreadsheet  to implement a recurrence relation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the expansion of $(x^5 + x^{10} + x^{20})^{10}$. The result you want will be the coefficient of $x^{100}$ in the expansion.

Wolfram Alpha says it is $\boxed{4351}$.